# react-native-maps integration issue with react-native 0.19.0

Tags: android, react-native

As per instructions of adding [react-native-maps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md), adding to MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .addPackage(new AirPackage()) // <---- and This!
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "MelBike", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);

}
```

I encountered this exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Attached DialogModule to host with pending alert but no FragmentManager (not attached to an Activity).
                                                           at com.facebook.infer.annotation.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:28)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.modules.dialog.DialogModule.onHostResume(DialogModule.java:199)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.onResume(ReactContext.java:140)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.moveReactContextToCurrentLifecycleState(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:761)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:599)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl.access$700(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:84)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:187)
                                                           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerImpl$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.onPostExecute(ReactInstanceManagerImpl.java:162)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is the source of the exception in react native code, DialogModule class:

```
public void onHostResume() {
mIsInForeground = true;
// Check if a dialog has been created while the host was paused, so that we can show it now.
FragmentManagerHelper fragmentManagerHelper = getFragmentManagerHelper();
Assertions.assertNotNull(
    fragmentManagerHelper,
    "Attached DialogModule to host with pending alert but no FragmentManager " +
    "(not attached to an Activity).");
fragmentManagerHelper.showPendingAlert();
```

I have tried to comment out the assertion in DialogModule class and run **react-native run-android** but it seems it was not reflected in compiled code that ran in my emulator.

Also tried to set the **LifecycleState.RESUMED** to **LifecycleState.BEFORE_RESUME** but then the app only loads blank screen and Dev menu wasn't functioning properly.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does the rest of your activity look like? I ran into this but the problem was that I was not implementing **DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler** in my activity.

Here is how they are implemented:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onResume( this, this );
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mReactInstanceManager != null) {
        mReactInstanceManager.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that what I found out at the end by going back to basic tutorial of Facebook, hopefully this would help other newbies that started out using 3rd party libraries straight away and skipping original tutorial :)